# Overriding DateTime.Now

Tags: .net, time

When we do development/QA we often need to pretend that current date/time is something other than now. It is pretty common for us to have some sort of logic that relies on date.

Simple example: say a product in the store is available between Dec 15 2010 to Jan 3 2011. These two dates would be stored in DB, and code would compare it to `DateTime.Now`. This obviously needs to be [unit]tested somehow. Question is how?

So far we just added a custom `Date` object and attempted to enforce using `Date.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now`, which does not cover any third party code that may rely on current date and is also feels super lame.

I wonder is there is a bit more kosher way of handling date override without changing system date in Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For unit testing I would recommend you to take a look at [Microsoft Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/), an isolation framework that would let you replace a call to `DateTime.Now` with your own delegate which could return any date you wanted.

Comment: I like this alot better. What is the setup effort? Can I use this without VS project?

Comment: The setup is simple and documentation is available. What exactly do you mean by running without VS project? You'll need to compile the unit tests that use Moles and those unit tests will need to run under the Moles profiler in order for them to work.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase this. Can I use Moles with MbUnit or NUnit?

Comment: Yes, Moles provides out of the box support for NUnit, MBUnit and also XUnit I believe. However, the supported version may not be for the last version available. If you require support for a specific version let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way in pure .net, you need to call [`Win32SetSystemTime` function using pinvoke](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/37406-Change-System-date-time.aspx)

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option since development is done in web context, so the same server maybe running a few dozens of application and only specific one of them needs to be affected.

Comment: Please keep in mind that changing the system time, can have negative side effects, especially in combination with other programs/applications.